# Use Values from a Dropdown to save an Excel workbook (using VBA Code)

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macro, but have some basic idea how it works or like able to write small VBA codes.

> > Is it possible to add some predefined values inside a VBA code which can be used as a dropdown value and which can be used later, as per google there are two types of response like 'Yes we can use it' & some others says 'its impossible'.

I was trying to create a report. and I have to save it with some values like

*1. Predefined value, like("Analysis_Report" will be constant value)

2. DropDown value ("Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Other") - Not able get it

3. Date and Time stamp

4. InputBox ("UserName")*

But I am not able to set the dropdown (tried ComboBox) to my macro. If someone can help me correct my code it will be really thankful. :)

A portion of Macro I used was given below for your reference

```
Sub ImporttoNew_WorkBook_and_Close ()  
Dim DT As String  
Dim wbNam As String  
Dim Path  
Dim Cluster  
Dim UserName  

Workbooks.Add  
wbName = "Analysis_Report"

DT = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss") 

Path = InputBox("Enter Path ", "Enter value") & "\"  
UserName = "_" & InputBox("Type your Name", "Enter value")   
Cluster = ComboBox1.List = Array("Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Other") **'Not Working**  

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Cluster & wbName & DT & UserName   
ActiveWorkbook.close   
MsgBox "Document saved"   

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Instead of prompting for a username, you can do something like: `UserName = (Environ$("Username"))` which would grab the username of the logged on user. Is there something that VBA could check to automatically determine `Cluster1`, `Cluster2`, `Other`?

Comment: Thank you Davis,  it really help me in a different way... Thanks for helping me!!!!                                     
                                                                                                                    And sorry some part of the code was not copied properly, I just updated the query again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the combobox is in the following row:

```
Cluster = ComboBox1.List = Array("Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Other") **'Not Working**
```

You have to set cluster as your combobox first and then assign the values:

```
Set Cluster = Tabelle1.ComboBox1  'change Tabelle1 to the Codename of the worksheet with your combobox1 in it
Cluster.List = Array("Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Other")
```

Comment: Thanks Jochen, but the code not working for me, I changed 'Tabelle1' to 'Sheet1' ( I used "MsgBox Worksheets(1).CodeName" to find the correct value) but when I run the code I am getting this error "Compile Error: Method or Data member not found".   Please help me to resolve this issue... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please check the name of the combobox, if it isnt `Combobox1`, then change correspondingly. If you start typing `Sheet1.` you see the existing objects.

Comment: This will work If I add below code inside Thisworkbook & select the value from a Combobox placed in my sheet. I was looking for something which prompt the user to select the value from a drop down list if he try to save the file like a Inputbox (like i used Path=InputBox()). So is this really possible ???  And if u r trying to say something different from what i understood please take & correct my whole code and send it back to me which will be really thankful :)

Comment: Private Sub Workbook () With WithSheet1.ComboBox1
.AddItem "Cluster1"
.AddItem "Cluster2"
.AddItem "Other"
End With End Sub

Comment: Either you put you Combobox in your sheet (all the time or add it by code on runtime and delete again before saving), or you create a userform with a combobox, put the `cb.List = Array(..)`in the `initialize` event. Then open the userform with `myuserform.show`.